# Is this not tail recursive? (stack overflow error)

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, recursion, tail-recursion

This is a small function I have written to check whether an integer is a prime or not:

```
int prime(int x, int y = 2)
{
    if(y <= x/2)
    {
        if((x % y) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;

    return prime(x, ++y);
}
```

Now, I compile it with visual studio 2012, and if i give it a large value such as 105943, a stack overflow error occurs and the code breaks. Now, is this function not tail recursive? If so then a stack shouldn't be maintained for the recursive calls, and an overflow should not occur?

What am I not getting here exactly?

Comment: Yes, it is tail recursive, but the compiler you used didn't optimise the tail recursion to a loop.

Comment: You won't get tail recursion in C++, without some tricks: see e.g. http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload109.pdf

Comment: Is there a flag i need to set or something similar, that would make the compiler optimize it? specifically visual studio?

Comment: Thumbs up to the smarta$$, who read my question, voted it down, posted a comment, and then realized he was wrong and deleted his comment.

Comment: @user1831704 The compiler should do it if you specify a high optimisation level (don't know how to do that in Visual Studio). (clang is happy with `-O`, gcc needs `-O2` to make a loop of it)

Comment: I don't use that compiler, but [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6200f5dd-7164-4f0f-9791-aa7cabdc135c/c-tail-call-optimization) suggests that the tail call will be optimised at a suitably high optimisation level.

Comment: Or.. you could just write it as an iterative algorithm in the first place? Just a thought.

Comment: Just a remark, you don't have to get to x/2, you only need to verify till the square root of x. this way for x = 105943. you you will win 50 000 call to the function prime.

Comment: With little thought it should have been possible to come up with a much more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Idk, for me this code works perfectly.

Comment: @MalekBensalem thanks man, nice pointer!

Comment: @WhozCraig, yeah i know, but the goal was to use recursion, tail recursion at that

Comment: @devnull if its anything other than using squareroot of x like malek suggested, and still uses tail recursion, please do add in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a tail recursive function, but there's no requirement for any compiler to optimise tail recursion into a loop. The chances are if you've got optimisation levels set high enough, it'll do so. But that's all.

LISP (and derived languages) are the only ones I know of where tail recursion is actually a requirement of the implementation.